# Some questions about rpart & gbm in R

Tags: r, rpart, gbm

I am trying to model the claim frequency with the rpart and gbm packages. And I have a few questions regarding these packages.

1. In the rpart-model, what is the purpose/function of the shrink-parameter?
2. In the gbm-model, do I use the weights correct? I get an output (no errors), but I just want to be sure I have understood it correct.
3. I the gbm-model, I know that the parameter n.minobsinnode let me say that it should at least be 10 observations in each node. But is there a way to say that each node should have at least 1 claim? I don’t want a model that predicts 0 in claim frequency for some observations.
4. In RandomForest, d variables are randomly picked from the n variables for each split. But in the gbm-model, all n variables are considered for each split?
5. In tree-based-models, is it possible to offset one variable (e.g. deductible)?

   ## Regression tree

   ```
   Model_tree <- rpart(cbind(duration, nclaims) ~ Var_1 + … + Var_n , 
                       data = data , 
                       method = "poisson",
                       parms = list(shrink = 1),control=rpart.control(minbucket = 10, cp = 0.00005 , maxdepth = 5))

   # Gradient Boosting Model       
   Model_gbm <- gbm(nclaims ~ Var_1 + … + Var_n,
                    data = data,
                    weights = duration,
                    distribution = "poisson",
                    cv.folds = 0,
                    shrinkage = 0.01,
                    interaction.depth = 5,
                    n.trees = 5000,
                    n.minobsinnode = 10,
                    bag.fraction = 1, 
                    train.fraction = 1)

   # Predict with a gbm
   predict.gbm(object = Model_gbm, n.trees = 1000, newdata = testdata, type = "response")
   ```

Comment: Some of your questions can be answered by reading the docs I think. **In the rpart-model, what is the purpose/function of the shrink-parameter?** I can't see the shrink parameter in there though. What's your rpart version?

Comment: **1.**  - I saw it in one example before, and now I just found it in rpart.exp.